# Print exception error message to console

Tags: java

I am struggling to print an error message to the console when calling the getCurrent() method within my print() method. Also, in my getCurrent() method the compiler says i need to return a double. I don't understand the return double problem, shouldn't the try catch block wrap around the call to getCurrent().

getCurrent method:

```
    public double getCurrent() throws IllegalStateException{
    //check if element
    try{
        if(isCurrent() == true){
            return data[cursor];
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException
            ("No Element");
        }//end check        
    }//end try
    catch(IllegalStateException e){
        //print error message to console
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }//end catch        
}//end method
```

isCurrent() method:

```
    public boolean isCurrent(){
    if(cursor < manyItems){
        return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
}//end method
```

print() method:

```
    public void print(){
    double answer;
    System.out.println(" Capacity = " + data.length);
    System.out.println(" Length = " + manyItems);
    System.out.println(" Current Element = " + getCurrent());
    System.out.print("Elements: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < manyItems; i++){
        answer = data[i];
        System.out.print(answer + " ");
    }//end loop
    System.out.println(" ");
}//end method
```

main method (can't be adjusted):

```
  DoubleArraySeq x = new DoubleArraySeq();
  System.out.println("sequence x is empty");
  x.print();
  System.out.println("Trying to get anything from x causes an exception\n");
  System.out.printf("%5.2f", x.getCurrent());
```

Correct output:

sequence x is empty

capacity = 10

length = 0

No Element

elements:

Trying to get anything from x causes an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public double getCurrent() throws IllegalStateException{
    //check if element
    try{
        if(isCurrent() == true){
            return data[cursor];
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("No Element");
        }//end check        
    }//end try
    catch(IllegalStateException e){
        //print error message to console
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }//end catch        
}//end method
```

You catch your own `throws IllegalStateException`. remove your `try{}catch(){}`

```
public double getCurrent() throws IllegalStateException{
    //check if element
    if(isCurrent() == true){
        return data[cursor];
    }else{
        throw new IllegalStateException("No Element");
    }//end check      
}//end method
```

the main:

```
try{

    DoubleArraySeq x = new DoubleArraySeq();
    System.out.println("sequence x is empty");
    x.print();
    System.out.println("Trying to get anything from x causes an exception\n");
    System.out.printf("%5.2f", x.getCurrent());
}catch(IllegalStateException e){
    System.err.println("This exception produce because there is no element");
}
```

Comment: Now I get an error from Java: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Element
 at DoubleArraySeq.getCurrent(DoubleArraySeq.java:144)
 at DoubleArraySeq.print(DoubleArraySeq.java:202)
 at DoubleArraySeqDemonstration.main(DoubleArraySeqDemonstration.java:48) Instead of the "no element" error message being printed to console.

Comment: It's correct. You need to try{}catch(){} now in the main or when calling `getCurrent()` I will add it to my answer

Comment: I moved your try{}catch(){} to the print method since I can't adjust the main. I also switched .err to .out and it works except for one problem. Since I can't adjust the main code the x.getCurrent() produces java error I mentioned in my previous response. I am guessing the only way to solve the problem is something within the getCurrent() method. At a loss of how to solve it.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. But every time you call `getCurrent()`, you must put it in a try catch to avoid Java to print the exception out.

Comment: If the main method does not catch the exception and you can't change the main method and the main method calls a method which throws an exception: There is nothing that you can do. Java will terminate and print the non caught exception to the console.

Comment: My problem is I can't adjust the main code, it must remain as is. So I can't put a try catch in the main. Somehow when `getCurrent()` is called in the main with `printf()` nothing gets printed to console or Java.

Comment: Ok, So I assume you can edit the `print()` method you wrote. change it like that: `try{System.out.println(" Current Element = " + getCurrent());}catch(IllegalStateException e){System.out.println(" no current element")}` and you must remove the throws IllegalStateException from your `getCurrent()` if the user cannot try{}catch(){}. Because double cannot be null.

Comment: There is no other solution, if the main cannot be edited than return a default value

Comment: That solves the problem. Having try{}catch(){} in the `print()` method.